# Stopping Nested Timeouts in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to execute a piece of arbitrary code and be able to stop it whenever I want. I figured I could do this with `setTimeout` and then use `clearTimeout` to stop it. However if the code in the timeout creates it's own timeouts, then those keep executing even after I clear the original.

Example:

```
var timeoutID = setTimeout(
    function(){
        console.log("first event can be stopped with clearTimout(timeoutID)");
        setTimeout(function(){console.log("but not this one")}, 5000)
    }, 5000)
```

Now one way would be to control the code being executed and make it store the value of any additional timeouts into a global variable and clear them all at once. But is there a better way to do this? And is there a way to do this on arbitrary code?

To clarify, I'm trying to be able to execute any function I want, then stop it whenever I want, even if the function contains timeouts

Comment: please clarify your question what exactly do you want to be able to do?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight I want to execute any function and be able to stop it from executing at any time, even if the function uses it's own timeouts.

Comment: please edit your question

Answer (score 3):

You can put the inner timeout into a variable too:

```
var innerTimeout,
    timeoutID = setTimeout(
    function(){
        console.log("first event can be stopped with clearTimout(timeoutID)");
        innerTimeout = setTimeout(function(){console.log("but not this one")}, 5000);
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: And he definitely should too

Comment: Why not re use timeoutID? Completion of the first timeout will start the second one. The case that the OP just wants to cancel the whole thing you can just use timeoutID to clear it.

Comment: @HMR If there won't be overlapping calls, reusing is fine. With two variables you have better _control_ over triggered timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create an array of timeout IDs such as this:

```
var timeoutIds = [];

timeoutIds.push(setTimeout(
  function(){
    console.log("first event can be stopped with clearTimout(timeoutID)");
    timeoutIds.push(setTimeout(function(){console.log("but not this one")}, 5000));
 }, 5000))
```

And then to clear:

```
for (int i = 0; i < timeoutIds.length; i++)
{
   clearTimeout(timeoutIds[i]);
}

timeoutIds  = [];
```

Comment: No need for that because the second timeout runs when the first is completed, by that time it doesn't make sense to clear the first one. In case multiple timeouts are set then an array can be used but in this case the second timeout is initiated by the first one so OP can re use timeoutID

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your timeouts in an object or re use timeoutID for the second timeout.

Wrap in an object:

```
function Timer(){
  var me=this;
  this.currentTimerID=setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("First timeout");
    me.currentTimerID=setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Second timeout");
    },100);
  },100);
};
Timer.prototype.cancel=function(){
  clearTimeout(this.currentTimerID);
};

var t = new Timer();//let this run it's course
setTimeout(function(){t = new Timer()},250);//start timer again
setTimeout(function(){t.cancel();},400);// cancel it after the first timeout
```

Re use timeoutID:

```
var timeoutID = setTimeout(
    function(){
        console.log("first event can be stopped with clearTimout(timeoutID)");
        timeoutID=setTimeout(function(){console.log("but not this one")}, 100)
    }, 100)
setTimeout(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
},150);// will not execute the second timeout
```

One tip: If you're testing code with timeout then don't use such high values as it'll take 10 seconds for your original code to run.