# How to stop nested timeOut with same names?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I am trying to use nested `timeOut` with the same names which is actually works like a loop, not exactly like it.
I try to use this example:

```js
let i = 1;
setTimeout(function run() {
  func(i);
  setTimeout(run, 100);
}, 100);
```

from this [link](http://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval).
As you see in this link, I cant use `interval` and `loop`.

Here is my actual code:

```js
let i = 0;
let x = setTimeout(async function run() {
  if(i == 2) {
    // I want to stop my x here completly
    console.log(i)
    clearTimeout(x);
  }
  try {
    //some code here e.g:
    console.log(10)
  } catch (err) {
    //some other code here e.g:
    console.log(err)
  }
  i++;
  x = setTimeout(run, 800);
}, 800);
```

And my output:

```
10
10
2
10
10
... //never stops
```

I also saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436465/stopping-nested-timeouts-in-javascript), but it is not my case.

Could any body please do something so that I can stop `x` completely?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to `return` from function after `clearTimeout` otherwise new timeout is created anyway few lines later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you `clearTimeout` you don't stop it by `return`. So your timeout will set another timeout with `x = setTimeout(run, 800);`. All you need to do is `return` your `clearTimeout(x)` to stop your timeout function.

```
    return clearTimeout(x);
```

In your code, I don't see any reason you need to clear timeout. Timeout run only once time. So if you execute it. It is done.

Answer (score 3):

You need not the timeout reference, because if inside of the function the reference is invalid, because the timeout is called. Then you need to stop just to return.

```js
let i = 0;
setTimeout(async function run() {
  if (i == 2) {
    console.log(i)
    return
  }
  try {
    //some code here e.g: 
    console.log(10)
  } catch (err) {
    //some other code here e.g:
    console.log(err)
  }
  i++;
  setTimeout(run, 800);
}, 800);
```